# UICollectionView's cell registerClass in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Right now I'm using `NSClassFromString`, but is there a better way to get an `AnyClass`! from a class in Swift? I am trying to pass the reference to my collection view's `-registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` method.

```
collectionView.registerClass(NSClassFromString("MyCoolViewCell"), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCoolViewCell")
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

This is currently just a blind but educated guess, but using `Class.self` might be what you want.

```
collectionView.registerClass(MyCoolViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCoolViewCell")
```

Comment: This is really bad syntax, but is seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Bad syntax? `.self` is very concise.

Comment: `self` in most languages (similar to `this`) almost always refers to an instance of the class, I think that's why a having `ClassName.self` refer to the Class type is confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the difference between self as a keyword and .self as a method name seems pretty clear to me.  One is a keyword, the other is a method.  Keywords should NOT automatically preclude the use of a method or property name matching them, though I will concede it's usually a good idea to avoid using them for clarities sake.  (It's important for the rare occasion when NOT using them is even more unclear, generally because you've been forced to use the thesaurus)

Comment: I am an Objective-C developer and I find this confusing but it works!

Comment: Objective-C has the same syntax, `UIButton.self` is equivalent to `UIButton.class`.

Comment: I find `UIButton.class` much more adequate than `UIButton.self`, pity they dropped this syntax from Swift.

Answer (score 23):

In case you are using a nib file, use this code instead:

```
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCoolViewCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView?.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCoolViewCellIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 15):

In Swift 3:

```
self.collectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCollectionViewCellReuseIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSClassFromString("MyCoolViewCell")`might get nil.
Should add module name in prefix:
`collectionView.registerClass(NSClassFromString("MyApp.MyCoolViewCell"), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCoolViewCell")`

If cellClass not a variable, use `MyCoolViewCell.self` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")